# Using a mysql alias in the same sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

How can I use an alias in the same statement? See the `body` alias in the statement below. When I use it in sum(length(body), I get `unknown column`.

```
SELECT substring_index(userBody, ' ', 60) as body, SUM(LENGTH(body)-LENGTH(REPLACE(body,' ',''))+1) as wordCount 
from articles where artcId = 10;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `body` alias name in the next select column, Better use the same 'alias' block in the following sections. See the below query for more clarification.

```
SELECT 
  substring_index(userBody, ' ', 60) AS body,
  SUM(
    LENGTH(substring_index(userBody, ' ', 60)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(substring_index(userBody, ' ', 60),' ',''))+1
  ) AS wordCount
FROM articles
WHERE artcId = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias column name to detch data for anothe column.

You can either use **subquery** or **use same function** for another column as explained below:

**Using Subquery**

```
SELECT body, SUM(LENGTH(body)-LENGTH(REPLACE(body,' ',''))+1) AS wordCount 
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(userBody, ' ', 60) AS body 
      FROM articles WHERE artcId = 10) AS A
```

**OR Using Same Function**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(userBody, ' ', 60) AS body, 
       SUM(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(userBody, ' ', 60))-LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(userBody, ' ', 60),' ',''))+1) AS wordCount 
FROM articles WHERE artcId = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't. alternatively, you can use subquery, eg.

```
SELECT  body,
        SUM(LENGTH(body)-LENGTH(REPLACE(body,' ',''))+1) as wordCount 
FROM
    (
        SELECT substring_index(userBody, ' ', 60) as body
        from articles 
        where artcId = 10
    ) s
```